# Does Elasticsearch-py sanitize queries?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I'm new to ES and wondering if the [search function](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.search) sanitizes the inner "query" field in the body parameter when handed something like:

```
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match": {
               "_all": {
                  "query": "[THIS PARAMETER]",
                  "operator": "and"
               }
            }
         }
       }
     }
```

I've tried every input I can to break it and I can't seem to. I created a sanitization function but that was actually leading to worse search results when searching strings such as "&" or "+". I've looked through the code and can't seem to find any obvious sanitization of that field. I just want to be sure before I send a user's search query right through the function.

Thanks

Comment: That query field is part of the JSON body, why would Python do anything to it?

Comment: Here's the source for [`search`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py#L453-L531)

Comment: Because it's a library that's meant to abstract much of the ES functionality. I figured it's possible it could be iterating the dictionary and sanitizing known inputs, the same way an ORM does that to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: Here is an elasticsearch sanitizer gist, based on a different StackOverflow question https://gist.github.com/eranhirs/5c9ef5de8b8731948e6ed14486058842

Answer (score 0):

I see three more possible approaches to validate es against an inverted attack against the indexes, which are databases, in an attack similar to SQL injection:

1. How well do you know Lucene and how it handles attacks? Pursuing Lucene architecture and supporting code directly may provide you with insight into how es handles attacks
2. Try a SOLR approach, which also uses Lucene, and see how SOLR handles    attacks; SOLR fell behind es, then has been catching up and improving other areas; there are some interesting SWOT architectural comparisons between es and SOLR
3. Lay down part of the ELK stack--at least Kibana and es, and test Kibana, which may generate other es/Lucene code that you could test